# Hover over image text slide out

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone could give me a hand - I will have a few Newsletter images, and when a user hovers over them, i would like the description text to appear to the right.

I have managed to accomplish the majority of this using HTML & CSS but cannot figure out how to make it look as if the text is sliding out of the image (From behind the image). At the moment it starts on top of the image. Also, it seems to be starting in the top left, i would love for it to just slide out to the right.

I have never been great with CSS positioning! :(

here is my code so far:

```
    #container{
    clear: both;

    top: 40px;
}

.image{

    float: left;

}

#container:hover div.text{
    width: 400px;
    position: relative; 
    left:80px;
    top: 10px;
    display: block;

    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5slinear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5slinear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5slinear;
    transition: all 0.5slinear;

}

.text{
        width: 400px;
display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;

    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    color: #f90;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5slinear;
    -o-transition: all 0.5slinear;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5slinear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5slinear;
    transition: all 0.5slinear;


}

    <div id="container">
    <div class="image"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="Newsletter_icon.jpg" height="55px" width="80px"/></a></div>
    <div class="text">This will be some text describing my newsletter...</div>
</div>

<div id="container">
    <div class="image"><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="Newsletter_icon.jpg" height="55px" width="80px" /></a></div>
    <div class="text">This will be some text describing my newsletter...</div>
</div>
```

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhtvu/

Comment: Got it working almost exactly like I wanted it to. Thanks for the below answers as well.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhtvu/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working almost exactly like I wanted it to. Thanks for the below answers as well. Updated fiddle: jsfiddle.net/Lhtvu/4

Comment: hah, the exactly that i was trying to do at Fiddle secs ago... :)

Answer (score 0):

There should be space in `all 0.5slinear` .The correct way is `all 0.5s linear`.See this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Lhtvu/1/

Comment: Fair enough :) But, it still not doing exactly what i want it to do. Question probably wasn't clear enough. How would I make it look as if the text is coming out from behind the image? Currently it slides from the top left in front of the image.

Answer (score 0):

**You made 2 mistakes:**

**One**: the `all 0.5slinear` should be `all 0.5s linear`.

**Two**: you need to set default positioning to `div.text` to make it slide, like that: `left:0px;` to it.

**See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhtvu/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here, it has been asked before. Look at this fiddle and restructure your CSS and HTML codes.

It works to perfection.

**HTML**

```
<div id="contain">
  <div class="fake-image"></div>
  <div class="text">some text</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#contain{
  clear: both;
}

.fake-image{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#contain:hover div.text{
     display: block;
}

.text{
    background-color: yellow;
    float: left; 
    display: none;    
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KdVaj/1/)